# A loop to pass a string to STD in

Tags: c, scripting, stdin

I'm a noob with pretty terrible programming skills.

I have a text file that reads like this:

(BIG STRING IN PARENTHESES) integer_value

(BIG STRING IN PARENTHESES) integer_value

(BIG STRING IN PARENTHESES) integer_value

(BIG STRING IN PARENTHESES) integer_value

I have a program that reads a string on stdin and returns a value.

I need some way to pass the string (and only the string) to the program and compare the value it returns with the one in the text file.

I tried to do this with a Bash script but I got really confused and frustrated, so I thought I'd try to do it with C.

```
int main(void)
{
int x;          
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("vectors.lst", "r");

if (fp == NULL) {
     printf("Failed to open\n");
     exit(0);
  }

    for(i = 1; i<10400; i++){


        //This is where I am confused

            while(fscanf(fp, "%s %d",passedstring,correctvalue) != EOF){

        printf("%s",passedstring);


            }
}
exit(0);
}
```

My problem is:

I don't know how to iterate through only the strings in the for loop, while still only reading until the end of the file. I'm starting to think using C for this was a terrible idea.

Can anyone offer some advice? I'm still open to using a script if there's an easy way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the string will end in a ')' why don't you can use getchar() to read the string.  Use something like:

```
  do {
    c=getchar();
    //process input
  } while (c != ')');
```

Comment: I could, that would require me to reprogram the main program (the one actually reading the string). If possible I'd like to pass it the whole thing parentheses and all. I basically just want to pass that program each string in the text file one at at time.

Comment: If you get the string in the main() function, you could just have this function iterate through it.  something like:

void func(char* str) {
   int i = 0;
   do {
        //some code
        i++;
   }
   while(str[i] != ')');
}

Answer (score 0):

There is something i don't know well but I feel like the follow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    int x;
    char buff[4096];
    FILE *fp;


    fp = fopen("vectors.lst", "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("search value: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp)){
        char *p;
        p=strrchr(buff, ' ');//(....) integer\n
        if(atoi(p+1) == x){//found! (correctvalue : from p+1)
            *p ='\0';
            printf("%s\n", buff);//copy
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, haven't done this in a while with the `<stdio.h>` library.  Some time ago, I wrote a document on this.  It's actually still floating around the net [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c/insights/657086-how-parse-file-c).  I re-read it, and it is still pretty good.  (Looks like someone even posted a comment a couple of years ago that I didn't respond to... oops).  Still, you might want to read it too.

Using the C stdio library, you can do most anything, but it can be fought with danger due to buffer overruns and badly handled error handling.  But it can be done (but my personal preference is to use perl if I can).

You haven't really specified much with this, but I'll give it a stab.  Something like this I think:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define STRINGIZE_(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE_(x)

int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("vectors.lst", "r");

  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to open\n");
    /* Exit return of non-zero to indicate an error to calling process */
    return 1;
  }

#define MAX_BUFFER 1024
  char passedstring[MAX_BUFFER+1];
  passedstring[MAX_BUFFER] = 0;
  int correctvalue = 0;
  int position;

  position = 0;
  /* " " - ignore any leading whitespace if any
   * "(" - match open parenthesis
   * "%" STRINGIZE(MAX_BUFFER) "[^)]" - store up to MAX_BUFFER chars 
   *       that are not ')'
   * ")" - match close parenthesis
   * " " - match any whitespace if any
   * "%d" - store int value
   * "%n" - store current read byte from fscanf(), if parse fails, store
   *        doesn't occur.  Ensures that everything has been read in.
   **/
  while(fscanf(fp, " (%" STRINGIZE(MAX_BUFFER) "[^)]) %d%n"
        , passedstring, &correctvalue, &position) != EOF
      && position > 0)
  {
    printf("%s, %d\n", passedstring, correctvalue);
    position = 0;
  }
  printf("End %d", position);

  /* Exit code returned here.  Not advised to use exit() for something like this. */
  return 0;
}
#undef MAX_BUFFER
```

Wasn't sure what your outer for loop was for.  This just reads till it get to the end of the file, or if a string is so big that it's bigger than the buffer.  If you want to do some recovery code, I'll leave it up to you.

I ran this through a compiler.  It's now verified to work.